# CakePHP - Date return value in localhost but return null in server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp, configuration

i have table staffs to store the information. The table is as below:

Table staffs -> id(int), name(varchar), password(varchar), last_login(datetime), created(datetime), modified(datetime),

In **localhost**, when I echo the date, for example the **created** date

`<?php echo h(date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($staff['Staff']['created']))); ?>`

it will return the value

```
05-07-2021 03:34 AM
```

In **Server** side, using the same code, it will return

```
01-01-1970 00:00 AM
```

After I checked, this is because the `$staff['Staff']['created']` in the **server** had return *null*. So the `strtotime()` will return 01-01-1970 00:00 AM.

This also happened to **last_login** and **modified**

What are the possible causes for this problem?

Both localhost and server have the same timezone

```
date.timezone=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
```

Comment: If you were not expecting it to be `null`, it might be because you haven't cleared your ORM cache since adding new fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am not cakephp guy but I can understand the issue. The time has showd `01-01-1970 00:00 AM` because all time-tracking in computing is done as a count-since-1970. If you want to show just empty value then first check the value is empty or not.

```
<?php $staff['Staff']['created'] ? echo h(date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($staff['Staff']['created']))) : ''; ?>
```

Hope this will solve issue.